# Python, applying regex negative lookahead recursivly

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

In python, I am trying to implement a user defined regex expression by parsing it to a custom regex expression. this custom regex expression is then applied on a space-sperated string. The idea is to apply user regex on second column **without using a for loop**.

```
Stream //streams/sys_util mainline none 'sys_util'
Stream //streams/gta mainline none 'gta'
Stream //streams/gta_client development //streams/gta_cdevelop 'gta_client'
Stream //streams/gta_develop development //streams/gta 'gta_develop'
Stream //streams/gta_infrastructure development //streams/gta 'gta_infrastructure'
Stream //streams/gta_server development //streams/gta_cdevelop 'gta_server'
Stream //streams/0222_ImplAlig1.0 task none '0222_ImplAlig1.0'
Stream //streams/0377_kzo_the_wart task //streams/applications_int '0377_tta'
```

Expected output should be

```
//streams/gta
//streams/gta_client
//streams/gta_develop
//streams/gta_infrastructure
//streams/gta_server
```

here is my code,

```
import re
mystring = "..."
match_rgx = r'Stream\s(\/\/streams\/gta.*)(?!\s)'
result = re.findall(match_rgx, mystring, re.M)
```

**NOTE:** The expression inside first parenthesis can not be changed (as it is parsed from user input) so `\/\/streams\/gta.*` must remain as it is.

how can I improve negative look-ahead to get the desired results?

Comment: You are testing against some other input, right? Your pattern contains `tda_cl` that is missing from your input. You seem to need `r'Stream\s+(//streams/gta(?:_\w+)?)'`

Comment: Maybe `Stream\s(//streams/gta.*?)(?=\s|$)` (or `Stream\s(//streams/gta.*?)(?!\S)`) will do? It would be best if you could show the real, not simplified code you have.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. match_rgx should definitely countain gta.* as it comes from a user. I want to apply user defined regex only on second coloumn. hope this helps.

Comment: You cannot use `.*` there then. Anyway, "column" means you have delimited data and a `.` should never be used when parsing delimited data. If the data are tab-separated, replace such dots with `[^\t]`.

Comment: Whats the logic of including development on last line? `gta_client` also has the same pattern.

Comment: @MYGz it was a typo. its removed now.

Comment: @Sha Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
match_rgx = 'Stream\s(//streams/gta.*?)\s'
result = re.findall(match_rgx, mystring)
```

By default, the operator * is greedy, so it will try to catch as much text as possible (for example: "//streams/gta mainline none" will match without the ?). But you only want the second column, so, with ? your operator become non-greedy, and stop at the minimal pattern, here, at the first occurrence of \s ("//streams/gta").

Hope this is clear, put a look at the doc (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re) if it's not.

Btw, you don't have to escape the /, it is not a special character.
And it's useless to use the re.M flag if you don't use ^ or $.

Edit: Since your edit, if you don't want to catch development, some informations became useless.

Edit 2: Didn't see you don't want to change the pattern. In this case, just do:

```
match_rgx = 'Stream\s(\/\/streams\/gta.*?)\s'
```

Edit3: See comment.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. could you please explain what does ? after .* imply

Comment: @Sha I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @Sha Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it was useful enough.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on https://regex101.com/ , this should do the work for all 2nd columns:

```
(?:\w+\s([^\s]+)\s.*[\n|\n\r]*)
```

And this for the GTAs 2nd column only:

```
(?:\w+\s(\/\/streams\/gta[^\s]*)\s.*[\n|\n\r]*)
```

For one line it would be just like (2nd col):

```
\w+\s([^\s]+)\s.*
```

Gta only for 1 line:

```
\w+\s(\/\/streams\/gta[^\s]*)\s.*
```

Comment: unfortunately, '\/\/streams\/gta.*' cannot be changed as it would be a user input. The idea is to apply user defined regex expressions on second column.

Comment: If You take `\w+\s(\/\/streams\/gta[^\s]*)\s.*` (4th example) and change stream string to user input, it will work: `\w+\s(<user_input>[^\s]*)\s.*` If there is any trouble, I can't see it, could You be more explicit?

Comment: user input is **\/\/streams\/gta.*** Because .* includes everything it makes [^\s]*)\s.* becomes ineffective.

Comment: You asked for 2nd column, if You leave there `.*`, it will also take the rest of the row and whole line is the group. My solution telling explicitely "stop at the next space".